# How do you access an OFX server?

Tags: banking

My bank, ING Direct, has setup an OFX server. Details (public):

http://www.ofxhome.com/index.php/institution/view/658

I also obtained a "Personal Finance Access Code" from ING Direct, so I 
have everything I need to access the server... except any idea 
whatsoever how to use it.

What is the OFX protocol and where can I read more about it? I 
considered downloading GnuCash and looking at the source, but that 
seems kludgy.

Visiting https://ofx.ingdirect.com/OFX/ofx.html says "GET" is not 
supported, which makes sense (they probably support PUT, EDIT, DELETE 
or something).

I realize OFX is also the extension for Microsoft Money files, but I 
think this OFX is unrelated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.jongsma.org/gc/), under the "OFX" section, has pointers to an [OFX 2.0 spec (pdf)](http://www.jongsma.org/gc/ofx/200/ofx20.pdf).

You're looking for the info starting at page 18, section 1.2.1:

> Clients use the HTTP POST command to send a request to the previously acquired Uniform Resource Locator (URL) for the desired financial institution. The URL presumably identifies a Common Gateway Interface (CGI) or other process on an FI server that can accept Open Financial Exchange requests and produce a response.

and then shows some examples. The first page linked above also has some python scripts for downloading OFX data from your bank.

Comment: Thanks! I can now connect to the server, but it doesn't like my queries. But that's another question...

Comment: The links have rotted -- can someone update this or put the information in this post?